# Is there a way to check what's in a a block in Oracle that's similar to SQL Server's DBCC PAGE?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, storage, internals

Is there a way to check what's in a a block in Oracle that's similar to SQL Server's DBCC PAGE? I want to investigate how Oracle stores different data types. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It absolutely is.

```
ALTER SYSTEM DUMP DATAFILE <data file number> block <block number>;
```

See http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dump_block.html for details.

You should also read the Data types chapter in Expert Oracle Database Architecture book.